# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 're'

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following this ROS tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ckSl4MbZLg&t=84s and got the following error:

roslaunch mybot_gazebo mybot_world.launch

... logging to /home/mallikarjun/.ros/log/47f3e6c2-6153-11e7-9730-9439e5050f5a/roslaunch-mallikarjun-Ideapad-Z570-21214.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/lunar/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 55, in 
import xacro
File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/**init**.py", line 35, in 
import glob
File "/home/mallikarjun/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/glob.py", line 4, in 
import re

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 're'

Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/lunar/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/mallikarjun/mybot_ws/src/mybot_description/urdf/mybot.xacro'] returned with code [1].

Param xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file﻿

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265455/modulenotfounderror:-no-module-named-%27re%27/) by [mallikarjun.talagade](https://answers.ros.org/users/31025/mallikarjun.talagade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-07-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heyong](https://answers.ros.org/users/36807/heyong/) on 2018-08-03**:
hi，i have the same problem as it,How to solve this problem？thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The mixing of python 2.7 and 3.6 python files isn't good- you should have something like `/usr/lib/python2.7/glob.py` getting used instead of `/home/mallikarjun/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/glob.py`

It looks this isn't ROS related at all and you have installed anaconda3 into your home directory and need to keep it from being used.
If there are lines in your .bashrc putting anaconda3 on your PATH or PYTHONPATH or any other references to anaconda3 try disabling those and start a new terminal

A quick test is running python from the command line and typing `import re` in:

```
>>> import re
```

and see if that produces the same error.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mallikarjun.talagade](https://answers.ros.org/users/31025/mallikarjun.talagade/) on 2017-07-05**:
Thank you very much. Problem solved.
There were lines in .bashrc.

**Comment by [cydonia](https://answers.ros.org/users/31033/cydonia/) on 2017-07-05**:
I have a very similar problem [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/265477/turtlebot-launching-while-anaconda-is-installed/). Do you think uninstalling Anaconda and reinstalling to another directory could be a solution as well?

**Comment by [cydonia](https://answers.ros.org/users/31033/cydonia/) on 2017-07-05**:
And may I ask how exactly did you edit the .bashrc? the second line from the bottom looked like this at me: `export PATH="/home/cydonia/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` and I made it `export PATH="/home/cydonia:$PATH"`, but nothing changed.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-07-05**:
Did you start a new terminal and launch the ros software in that one?

**Comment by [cydonia](https://answers.ros.org/users/31033/cydonia/) on 2017-07-05**:
Just tried it and got another error, but then I run `source /home/cydonia/turtlebot3_ws/devel/setup.bash`  and now the simulator is running! Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on 2019-05-27**:
Thanks, this solves the problem. I had to comment out everything that included `conda` in my `~/.bashrc`. Also, `source ~/.bashrc` does not work, and I have to restart the terminal!

**Comment by [sujideevi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50760/sujideevi/) on 2020-01-30**:
I was breaking my head for the last 2 days. Finally, I landed on this page. Excluding 'anaconda3/bin' from $PATH resolved the issue. Thank you very much, guys!!!

**Comment by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on 2020-06-16**:
Dangit - I have the same problem, and I need python3.6 to use openai gym with ...so simply not using python3 is not an option